Calculating the efficiency of a solar cell based on the wattage of the lamp powering it
I am working to characterize some solar cells I have access to based on their material structure by measuring the IV curve of the cells. I can generally compare the cells by comparing their $P_{max-per-unit-area}$'s but I want to compare their efficiencies. For the efficiency of the cells I need to know what $P_{in}$ is. The paper that I am using as a reference use Solar Irradience (units of power per area)  data to calculate their $P_{in}$ but I am using a lamp. Actually I am using two lamps rated at $43 W$ and $60 W$. Here is my reasoning for calculating the $P_{in}$:
EDIT: I should have mentioned, the bulb is incandescent.
$43W$ of power is radiating out of the lamp while it is on but only a portion of that is hitting the solar cells. Therefore:
$$ I_{in} = P_{bulb} / A_{cells} $$
Where $I$ is the irradiance of the bulb and assuming that all of the possible power is hitting the solar cell. However, I'm not sure if this is an assumption that can be made since of course only a fraction of the bulb power is hitting the cells. Additionally, this only works if the area of the cells is some number $>1 m$. For example, I have a monocrystalline solar cell that is $0.13m * 0.15 m = 0.0195m^2$. Of course, $43 / 0.0195 =$ some huge value which will make the efficiency a huge value as well (The actual measured $P_{max}$ is about $0.29W$. I tried to resolve this by considering the solid angle of the radiation of the bulb.
I tried to change the assumption that all of the power is radiating onto the cells. I used this website to try and reason how much of the bulb is actually shining onto the solar cell. I tried to reason that about half of the sphere is radiating in the direction of the solar cells but I suspect that it could be more because the lamp-head is designed to have some amount of focus. Regardless, the equation becomes:
$$P_{in} = \frac{P_{bulb}}{4\pi} *A_{cells} $$
This reduces the previous efficiency from over $1000$% to ~$300$% so I guess thats an improvement. I could try to calculate the solid angle directly which would likely reduce the solid angle value and therefore increase the value of $P_{in}$ and thus the overall efficiency would go down.  However, I don't see it decreasing by $270$%.
In any case, am seeking feedback or perhaps I could be pointed in the right direction in case I am completely off.

I would not try to calculate the irradiance on the panel based on the wattage of the lamp, and the geometry of the reflector(s), diffuser(s), and/or other optics. I would measure the irradiance with a light meter. But, here's what I don't know how to do without doing some research first: Your lamp will emit some spectrum of light that may be different from the spectrum of sunlight. Your meter may be sensitive to a different spectrum.* Your solar panel will be sensitive to yet another spectrum. I'm not sure how to account for all of those different spectra.

* I Googled for "light meter," and my search mostly turned up cheap instruments that are calibrated to display illuminance (how bright the light looks to human eyes) rather than irradiance. You can tell illuminance measurements because they are reported in "lux" or in "foot candles," whereas irradiance should be reported in Watts per square meter.

43W of a lamp mostly goes to heat and not light. thats why we now us LED bulbs.

P.S., "...Where  is the irradiance of the bulb..." Light sources don't have irradiance. That's a measure of how much power falls on each unit area of some surface such as your solar panel. The power that a light source throws in a particular direction is called radiant intensity (Watts per steradian,) and the total power that it emits is its radiant flux (simply Watts.)

Voting to reopen. Clearly a question about the physics of light intensity and not an engineering question.


I am using two lamps rated at 43W and 60W ... 43W of power is radiating out of the lamp ...

This is almost certainly incorrect, especially if your lamps use LED bulbs. To simplify the transition from incandescent bulbs to LED bulbs, LED bulbs were described according to the equivalent incandescent bulb - so a "60W" LED bulb would emit as much light as an old 60W incandescent bulb. In fact, the power consumption of the LED bulb is much lower than this because it is more efficient than an incandescent bulb. A "60W" LED bulb only consumes $8$ to $12$ watts of electricity, and produces a light intensity of about $800$ lumens.
A typical LED bulb has a luminous efficacy of about $100$, so $800$ lumens corresponds to about $8$ watts per steradian. If you cells have an area $A$ and are a distance $d$ from the lamp, then the radiant energy that they receive from the "60W" lamp is about
$P_{in} = 8 \frac A {d^2}$
